# Using Play Framework 1.x, how do I get JPA to create missing DB tables in production mode?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

In development Play automatically creates missing tables and indexes in my database, but it doesn't seem to want to do this in production - which makes it hard to set up my production database.

How do I do this?

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this was supported at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must configure it in application.conf

```
# Specify the ddl generation pattern to use. Set to none to disable it 
# (default to update in DEV mode, and none in PROD mode):
# jpa.ddl=update
```

update will do the job, but be careful. It works fine if you add a column or table, but not more.